# Using store.dispatch with redux toolkit slice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have a redux toolkit slice as follow

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  value: null,
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAuth: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setAuth } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I can use `useDispatch` in function component as follow to setAuth

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth.value);

  const setAuthValue = (value) => {
    dispatch(setAuth(value));
  };
```

However, I have a scenario where I am not able to `useDispatch` hooks for this. (eg: inside axios interceptor)

Is that possible that I directly use `store.dispatch({'type': '', payload: {}}` like normal redux with above redux toolkit slice?

Or what is the better approach for it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and just got it working.  In the plain js file (outside a component function context), just import your `setAuth` action that you're exporting from your slice.  Then, you can dispatch it like so: `store.dispatch(setAuth(payload))`

Answer (score 1):

This is what `useDispatch` function in `react-redux` library:

```
function useDispatch() {
    const store = useStore()
    return store.dispatch
  }
```

You can export the store from `store.js` and use `store.dispatch`

Answer (score 1):

The pushback that I always got from the community around not dispatching directly from the `store` is that it was never meant to be a singleton (there could be more than one store) and that the store should be derived from the `Provider` rather than accessed directly.

However, having that in my back pocket, I have implemented projects with multiple stores and got the feedback that the Redux maintainers are suggesting only a single store per project in their documentation now: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#redux-store

Perhaps the non-singelton suggestion is meant more for like a test vs production type situation. But given that the maintainers are suggesting only 1 store per project, I don't see any reason not to dispatch directly from the store.